# Confused about CSS specificity

Tags: html, css, css-specificity

Given the following CSS and HTML, Can someone please explain why the header in the article tag is red, I thought it should be blue because they both have the same weight but the article style comes after the h4 style so should override the h4 style.

```
<html>
<head>
   <title></title>

   <style>
       h4
       {
            color:red;
       }

       article
       {
            color:blue;
       }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <article>
        <h4>Latest News</h4>
    </article>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easier to understand approach:

`<h4>` is closer to the text than `<article>`, and both are **element selector**, thus `<h4>` overrides `<article>`.

Comment: I think this answer is the best, very good/simple way to put it. +1

Answer (score 3):

Specificity has nothing to do with this. In the code, there is only one rule set sets `color` on the `h4` element, so that setting is applied.

If that rule were omitted, then `h4` would inherit `color` from its parent. But inheritance does not take place, for a property of an element, when *any* style sheet sets a value for that property of that element. Even here, specificity plays no role.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is a collision between the article's blue property and the H4 red property, the web browser will always choose the "closest" property.
So in this case, since the text is inside H4 which has the red property, it will show the text in red, but if you add some other text outside the H4 tag but inside the article tag, the text will be blue.